# Can I block tags on Delicious?

Tags: delicious, delicious-tags

There seem to be certain tags like `movie` or `video` in Delicious that get spammed by porn sites and the like. Is there any way to hide these sites, or report spam?

Alternatively, is it possible to block tags like `porn` or `sex`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Doesn't seem like you can ignore tags at this point in time. If it was possible, it could also be linked to [not have a certain tag show up](http://www.delicious.com/help/faq#tags) when viewing combinations of tags:

> #### Is there a way to use "not" in tag combinations? What about "or"?
>
> There's no way to use "not" yet; we'd like to do this in the future, but it's impractical for the time being. You can use "or", though, by creating a tag bundle that includes those tags.

However, you can report the abuse of a bookmark or site via the [Report Abuse](https://secure.delicious.com/help/abuse) page.